reconstruction issues with an variational autoencoder due to outliers
I'm trying to train a VAE and have the problem, that I'm getting a lot of outliers in my reconstruction. I'm trying to do a dimensional reduction of weather data using an VAE.
In the following you can see the plot of the original data and the reconstructed data. In the reconstruction I'm getting odd pixel errors. It seems that some grid points are diverging during the training. They are always at the same location.


(The outliers kill the color scale, otherwise it looks alright)
I've normalized the data in between -1 and 1. And also tried loss functions which are less sensitive for outliers (huber loss). Also I tried to add MaxPooling layers, which didn't help either.
I have an input shape of (120,480) and my encoder/ decoder look like:
self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_channels, out_channels=filters*2, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding=self.padding),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters*2),
        nn.Tanh(),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=filters*2, out_channels=filters*4, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding=self.padding),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters*4),
        self.activation,
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=filters*4, out_channels=filters*8, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding=self.padding),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters*8),
        self.activation,
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=filters*8, out_channels=filters*16, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding=self.padding),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters*16),
        self.activation,
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=filters*16, out_channels=filters*32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding=self.padding),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters*32),
        self.activation,
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=filters*32, out_channels=filters*64, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(1,2), padding=(0,1)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters*64),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
    )

self.fc_mean = nn.Linear(np.prod(self.encoder_shape[1:]), hidden_dim)
self.fc_log_var = nn.Linear(np.prod(self.encoder_shape[1:]), hidden_dim)



self.linear_out = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, np.prod(latent_dim[1:]))
            
self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=filters*64, out_channels=filters*32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(1,2), padding = (0,1), output_padding=(0,0)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters * 32),
        self.activation,
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=filters*32, out_channels=filters*16, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding = self.padding, output_padding=(1,1)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters * 16),
        self.activation,
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=filters*16, out_channels=filters*8, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding = self.padding, output_padding=(0,1)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters * 8),
        self.activation,
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=filters*8, out_channels=filters*4, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding = self.padding, output_padding=(1,1)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters * 4),
        self.activation,
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=filters*4, out_channels=filters*2, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding = self.padding, output_padding=(1,1)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(filters * 2),
        self.activation,
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=filters*2, out_channels=input_channels, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(2,2), padding = self.padding, output_padding=(1,1)),
        nn.Dropout2d(p=dropout_prob),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(input_channels),
        nn.Tanh(),
    )

For the training im using pytorch lightning with the train step function:
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, _ = batch
    x_decoded, mean, log_var = self.forward(x)
    
    reconstruction_loss = self.lossfunc(x_decoded, x)
    kld_loss = self.latent_space.kld_loss(mean, log_var).mean() 
    loss = reconstruction_loss + kld_loss * self.kld_weight 
    self.log_dict({"train_loss": loss, "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss, "kld_loss": kld_loss},batch_size=batch[0].size(0), on_step= False, on_epoch=True)

if anyone has an idea what could be causing the outliers in the reconstruction, I'd be happy to hear any suggestions.
